# AJAX send value from js to php

Tags: php, ajax

been tring to send var form js to php and do some manipulation but I keep receving this error. Is it even possible to send the value through to php?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>test</title>
    <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-xNzN2a4ltkB44Mc/Jz3pT4iU1cmeR0FkXs4pru/JxaQ="
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/d3js/5.15.1/d3.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
   <input type="text" name='name'>
    <p id="hey"></p>
   <?php 
     echo $_POST['name'];
   ?>
   <button id='button'>hi</button>
</body>
<script src="index.js"></script>
</html>
```

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    $.post("index.php",
    {
      name: "Donald Duck",
      city: "Duckburg"
    },
    function(data, status){
        $("#hey").append(status);
    });
  });
```

[image]

Comment: don't add code as screenshots.put related code as text

Comment: what's the issue? I can see for any error. Are you talking about ``undefined index name?`` ?

Comment: Yes Sir,  with this js code the index.php should have value of the name right?

Comment: what I actually  wanna do is to first show the user's request using js and then after the they confirm then send the one of the variable throught js to another php page and use that value to do something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created one index.php file here this should work for you.

```
<?php
if ($_POST) {
  echo json_encode(['data' => $_POST['name'], 'success' => true]);
  exit;
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>test</title>
    <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-xNzN2a4ltkB44Mc/Jz3pT4iU1cmeR0FkXs4pru/JxaQ="
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/d3js/5.15.1/d3.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
   <input type="text" name='name'>
    <p id="hey"></p>
    <div id='test'></div>
   <button id='button'>hi</button>
</body>
<script>
  let  data = {
      name: "Donald Duck",
      city: "Duckburg"
    };
$("#button").click(function(){
  $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'index.php',
  data: data,
  dataType: 'json'
}).done(function(response) {
      if (response.success) {
        $('#hey').html('success');
        $('#test').html(response.data);
      }
});
});
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not work because when you first load the page $_POST['name'] is undefined. Your javascript code does not trigger a submit (= reload to send the data). $_POST['name'] is never set because it will not be updated on the fly. To make this work make a separate php file which only handles the POST data from your javascript and returning a value.

```
/* call post.php and add console.log to track data */
$("#button").click(function(){
    $.post("post.php",
    {
      name: "Donald Duck",
      city: "Duckburg"
    },
    function(data, status){
        $("#hey").append(status);
        console.log(data);
    });
  });
```

```
<?php
// post.php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
  echo $_POST['name'];
}
```

This is of course very basic. In order to communicate effectively you should look into formating the data e.g. into JSON.

Comment: sir I adjusted my code like yours but still couldn't echo out $_POST['name'] but I don't have any notice or error message then 

btw from what I've learned the third paramater is optional so  if I don't care about the output statuse can I delete it?

Comment: I'm a little rusty on jquery. https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/#jQuery-post-url-data-success-dataType look here. It seems to be better to chain the $.post() with .done(data). Look at examples. You can also try to alert to see the value: alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );